# Interlocked update of field in struct vs class

Tags: c#, .net, class, struct

**Background**

I've have a stats object that has a number of counters as properties. The counters can be updated anywhere in the application. The stats object is a singleton class (which used to have public fields of type `long` and `int`). The fields were updated using `Interlocked.Increment`.

I changed the fields to properties and created a new class called `InterlockedInt64`, to encapsulate the call to `Increment`. I copy the previous stats object to a temporary filed in order to track a delta. I use the `Clone` method to do that since it is a class.

The simplified code is here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/baEm8E (and below).

**Problem**

If the `InterlockedInt64` was a struct, I wouldn't need the `Clone` method. But if I change it to a struct, the `Increment` doesn´t work anymore.

Can someone explain the mechanics behind? I just need to understand why using `long` wrapped in a custom struct isn't updated, but a `long` field is. I understand the difference between struct and class and all why using a class works.

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var test = new Stats();
        
        test.Counter.Increment();
        Console.WriteLine($"Expected 1, got {test.Counter}");
        test.Counter.Increment();
        Console.WriteLine($"Expected 2, got {test.Counter}");
        test.Counter.Increment();
        Console.WriteLine($"Expected 3, got {test.Counter}");
    }

    public class Stats
    {
        public InterlockedInt64 Counter { get; init; } = new InterlockedInt64();
    }
    
    //public class InterlockedInt64 // Works
    public struct InterlockedInt64 // Does not work
    {
        private long _value;
        public InterlockedInt64()
        {
            _value = 0;
        }

        public InterlockedInt64(long value)
        {
            _value = value;
        }

        public long Increment() => Interlocked.Increment(ref _value);
        public long Decrement() => Interlocked.Decrement(ref _value);
        public long Exchange(long newValue) => Interlocked.Exchange(ref _value, newValue);
        public InterlockedInt64 Clone() => new(_value);
        
        public static implicit operator InterlockedInt64(long v)
        {
            return new InterlockedInt64(v);
        }

        public static implicit operator long (InterlockedInt64 v)
        {
            return v._value;
        }

        public override string ToString() => _value.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        public string ToString(CultureInfo cultureInfo) => _value.ToString(cultureInfo);
    }
}
```

*edit: Removed some code and renamed Test -> Stats*

Comment: `Test.Counter` is a struct, so it's returned by value - so it's returning a COPY of `test.Counter`. You are incrementing the copy, and then printing (another copy of) the original.

Comment: Be aware that on 32 bit systems, reading `_value` like you are doing is not atomic, and that on 64 bit systems, while it will probably be atomic because of how C# aligns fields, you might still run into some problems that would require a memory barrier. Use `Interlocked.Read()` for reading `_value`.

Comment: @JonasH In the real code it is a singleton injected via a `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`. It is only used for collecting statistics and logging. 

I needed a number of counters that are incremented. The `InterlockedInt64` is a single object that manages the shared state for the specific counter. True, it does belong to a global singelton object. 

It does not matter when or in which order the counters are updated. I just need a delta and the total count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When working with `struct`, you have to deal with their *copies*, not *shared references* (`struct` is passed by *value*, not by *reference*):

```
// you get a copy of test.Counter which you Increment and then throw it away
// note, that original test.Counter (its backing field) is not changed
test.Counter.Increment();
// you get a copy of test.Counter (which is unchanged) and print it out
Console.WriteLine($"Expected 1, got {test.Counter}");
```

If you insist on working with `InterlockedInt64` being `struct`, you can try dealing with *references* to `struct`:

```
public class Test {
  // Backing field
  private InterlockedInt64 m_Counter = new InterlockedInt64();

  // we want to return reference (not copy) of the m_Counter
  public ref InterlockedInt64 Counter {
    get {
      // and we return reference to the original field (not its copy)
      return ref m_Counter;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured it had something to do with copying the value, but I couldn't figure out when. But obviously when I do `test.Counter` it will return a copy.

Not sure if struct is the better option here, though. Might keep it as a class. It doesn't really matter, I just need to know.